# file is downloading without propername and extension

Tags: javascript, html, file, download

In my project I have a feature for downloading the file, the file comes like as shown below. when I click the hyperlink it will trigger the download but without proper name and file extension. But within the hyperlink the exact name of the file is mentioned as **angular-treasure-overlay-spinner-master.zip**.

Can anyone please tell me how to download the file as the exact name specified within the hyperlink (**angular-treasure-overlay-spinner-master.zip**)

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxk90pue/)**

```
<div class="well text-left">
     <img src="https://api.kandy.io/v1.2/devices/content/thumbnail?key=UAT5b6f2e196b0a4e0793ff17ac44b6404c&amp;content_uuid=7DF8CD44-B614-4C4A-82F3-1C5E36B4CC02&amp;device_id=FF4A88BA0C2840749D5AB91584C29E4D&amp;thumbnail_size=500x500" style="width: 20px;"/>
     <a href="https://api.kandy.io/v1.2/devices/content?key=UAT5b6f2e196b0a4e0793ff17ac44b6404c&amp;content_uuid=7DF8CD44-B614-4C4A-82F3-1C5E36B4CC02&amp;device_id=FF4A88BA0C2840749D5AB91584C29E4D" target="_blank">angular-treasure-overlay-spinner-master.zip</a>
</div>
```

Comment: the "hyperlink" text is not the same as the "hyperlink"

Comment: sorry....here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jxk90pue/

Comment: I am not getting this `"hyperlink" text is not the same as the "hyperlink"`

Comment: how can we get in that name and extension, if we download the file and change the extension to .zip, I am able to get all the contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK major edit for those who are watching

After you've got FileSaver from https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ and added it to your page:

```
function getAndSaveUrl(url, name, mime) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: mime});
        saveAs(blob, name); // Note: this is the FileSaver.js function
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

add this function

```
function doDownload(el) {
    getAndSaveUrl(el.href, el.textContent, "application/zip");
    return false;
}
```

change your html above to

```
<div class="well text-left">
     <img src="https://api.kandy.io/v1.2/devices/content/thumbnail?key=UAT5b6f2e196b0a4e0793ff17ac44b6404c&amp;content_uuid=7DF8CD44-B614-4C4A-82F3-1C5E36B4CC02&amp;device_id=FF4A88BA0C2840749D5AB91584C29E4D&amp;thumbnail_size=500x500" style="width: 20px;"/>
     <a href="https://api.kandy.io/v1.2/devices/content?key=UAT5b6f2e196b0a4e0793ff17ac44b6404c&amp;content_uuid=7DF8CD44-B614-4C4A-82F3-1C5E36B4CC02&amp;device_id=FF4A88BA0C2840749D5AB91584C29E4D" onClick="return doDownload(this);">angular-treasure-overlay-spinner-master.zip</a>
</div>
```

Tested in firefox, everything up to the saveAs works - haven't tested that part because jsfiddle doesn't have FileSaver.js available - but I use fileSaver at work, and have had no issues with it